# How to plan for production cut over while migrating from on prem to azure sql database?

Tags: sql, cloud, azure-sql-database, database-migration, continuous-deployment

As of today , we have on- prem service pointing to on-premise sql database and we are planning to migrate the components to cloud in phases i.e

1. Create the database in cloud
2. Migrate the data from on prem to sql cloud using replication
3. Plan the cut over i.e point on prem service to sql cloud
4. Cloud service to cloud db

we are done with 2 steps and good for production but while coming to point 3 , This is what we initially have planned but i feel still there is better way to achieve it without down time and in faster way

1. First, do data compare with between cloud and on-prem using visual studio 
   data compare
2. If everything looks good i.e no data mismatch, then take some downtime and point the service to cloud DB and bring them online.

I feel that data compare at the DB level will take lot of time to get the results and also taking production down is not good idea , so looking for some best practices to achieve it in more better way

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: How large is your data, and how much downtime can you afford?

Comment: we will be setting up the transaction replication a way head so that all data get replicated to azure and okay with half -1 hour down time to cut the traffic and do data compare .. but data compare is taking lot of time and i want to minimize it  ( 45 min ) because i cannot get back the server pointing to sql azure till we have zero mismatch between 2 db

Comment: If HA is a possibility, you could set up an HA between `Source` and `Destination` in `Async Commit` mode. a few hours before the switch, change to `Sync Commit`. At switch time: stop all data traffic to `Source`, take `Destination` databases out of HA and recover, point application to `Destination`. Depending on the size of database, you'll be looking at 10-15 minutes downtime at most.

Comment: Have a look at Data Migration Assistance from Microsoft which is free and has just been updated to v3.3: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595

Answer (score 0):

May you can use the following tools and services

**Azure Database Migration Service**
DMS is a fully managed service designed to enable seamless migrations from multiple database sources to Azure Data platforms with minimal downtime. Recommend for the large databases and size.

**Data Migration Assistant:**
Check SQL databases for compatibility, and then migrates the schema and data to Azure. Its recommended for the small database and data size.

**Data Migration Tool**
Migrates existing databases to Azure Cosmos DB. Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration tool, which can import data from different sources into Azure Cosmos containers and tables. Data can be imported from JSON files, CSV files, SQL, MongoDB, Azure Table storage, Amazon DynamoDB, and even Azure Cosmos DB SQL API collections. Also, the Data Migration tool can be used to migrating from a single partition collection to a multi-partition collection for the SQL API.

You can visit for "[Azure Migration Planning Step by Step](https://sps-cloud-architect.blogspot.com/2019/12/azure-migration-planning-step-by-step.html)"